# How to confirm a caller id number was used?

Tags: c#, twilio, caller-id

I'm creating a `CallResource` using code like this:

```
var resource = CallResource.Create(
    twiml: "<some TwiMl>",
    from: "+12225551234",
    to: new PhoneNumber("+17235551234"),
    callerId: "<Twilio number I own>"
);
```

I can see the call being created in the console and the `from` and `to` numbers are the one entered in those fields but I can't see the `callerId` number anywhere.

How can I confirm that the caller id entered was correctly used?

Comment: That's a good question, a [call resource](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/api/call-resource) doesn't return the `callerId` as a property. Can I ask why you might be making a call with a different `callerId` to the `from`?

Comment: I'm dialing person A into a conference with person B and want the call to appear to come from B not the conference call number.

Comment: You can use B as the `from` number then.

Comment: How does the call go to the conference if the `from` doesn't reference it?

Comment: What the call does is based on the TwiML, not on the number you are calling from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the case where you are creating a `CallResource` to connect an external party to a conference call the `from:` field is not used to make a call. This means you can set it to whatever you want (I didn't test if this number was constrained by the verified caller id system since all our numbers are bought through Twilio)

`CallerId` doesn't seem to be used in this case.